# Understanding Android Memory Leaks in combination with RxJava

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, rx-java, rx-android

I still do not understand how memory leaks appear.

I know that if something that is used (like an singleton) holds a reference to sth else this object can't be garbage collected and the available memory goes down.

But in what scope does that happen? I use RxBinding to create and Observable from click events.
The scope is [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding/view/RxView.java#L76) and it says:

> *Warning:* The created observable keeps a strong reference to {@code view}. Unsubscribe
>       to free this reference.

Why is this necessary? 
When I set a manual listener as an anonymous inner class in onCreate it has a reference to to the activity, right? But why can't the whole activity-view-observable-subscription be garbage collected any more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I set a manual listener as an anonymous inner class in onCreate it has a reference to to the activity, right? But why can't the whole activity-view-observable-subscription be garbage collected any more?

In this simple case, it can be garbage collected and you shouldn't have a leak.

> Why is [unsubscription] necessary?

It might not be strictly necessary, as in the example you gave above. As the documentation states, it is simply a warning that you should be aware of. However, it is a good practice to follow.

The issue is that you could be performing other tasks in the Rx chain that could cause a leak in combination with the RxBinding calls. For example:

```
RxViews.clicks(clickableView)
    .flatMap(view -> getDataFromApi()
    .subscribe(data -> onDataLoaded(data));
```

In this case, we are getting data from an API when the button is clicked using another Observable. That Observable still has a reference to the click Observable, and thus the referenced View can't be garbage collected until our API call returns (which might be never).